# Getting specific data values out of a dataframe - python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Python using pandas.  It has 2 columns called 'dropoff_latitude' and 'pickup_latitude'.  I want to make a function that will create a 3rd column based on these 2 variables (runs them through an api).

So I wrote a function:

```
def dropoff_info(row):
    dropoff_latitude = row['dropoff_latitude']
    dropoff_longitude = row['dropoff_longitude']
    dropoff_url2 = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json&latitude=%s&longitude=%s&showall=true" %(dropoff_latitude,dropoff_longitude)
    dropoff_resp2 = requests.get(dropoff_url2)
    dropoff_results2 = json.loads(dropoff_resp2.text)
    dropoffinfo =  dropoff_results2["Block"]["FIPS"][2:11]
    return dropoffinfo
```

then I would run it as
    df['newcolumn'] = dropoffinfo(df)

However it doesn't work.

Upon troubleshooting I find that when I print dropoff_latitude it looks like this:

```
0     40.773345947265625
1     40.762149810791016
2     40.770393371582031
...
```

And so I think that the URL can't get generated.  I want dropoff_latitude to look like this when printed:

```
40.773345947265625
40.762149810791016
40.770393371582031
...
```

And I don't know how to specify that I want just the actual content part.

When I tried

```
dropoff_latitude = row['dropoff_latitude'][1]
dropoff_longitude = row['dropoff_longitude'][1]
```

It just gave me the values from the 1st row so that obviously didn't work.

Ideas please?  I am very new to working with dataframes... Thank you!

Comment: You're sending a dataframe with multiple rows into a function that ostensibly is looking for a single row. I think you're going to have to iterate through all the rows, but it's probably best to create a list with your API responses then add that list as a new column once complete. That sound right?

Comment: Also, good on you for asking a well written question for your first question on SO.

Comment: Hi, @pshep123 - thank you!  I think iterating makes sense but I don't know how to do that...  :(

Comment: Making a list seems more within my skillset!!  Do you think that it will be a bigger drain on the memory to make a separate list and then add it as a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex - with pandas we typically like to avoid loops, but in your particular case, the need to ping a remote server for data pretty much requires it.  So I'd do something like the following:

```
l = []
for i in df.index:
    dropoff_latitude = df.loc[i, 'dropoff_latitude']
    dropoff_longitude = df.loc[i, 'dropoff_longitude']
    dropoff_url2 = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json&latitude=%s&longitude=%s&showall=true" %(dropoff_latitude,dropoff_longitude)
    dropoff_resp2 = requests.get(dropoff_url2)
    dropoff_results2 = json.loads(dropoff_resp2.text)
    l.append(dropoff_results2["Block"]["FIPS"][2:11])

df['new'] = l
```

The key here is the `.loc[i, ...]` bit that gives you the ability to go through each row one by one, and call out the associated column to create the variables to send to your API.

Regarding your question about a drain on your memory - that's a little above my pay-grade, but I really don't think you have any other options in this case (unless your API has some kind of batch request that allows you to pull a larger data set in one call).